# 'telegram-send' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I used cmd prompt to install telegram-send successfully.

`pip3 install telegram-send`

Then, I am trying to configure it in cmd prompt.

`telegram-send --configure`

but I am getting the following error:
`'telegram-send' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

1.Find telegram-send location

```
sudo find / -name telegram-send
```

2.copy the result to /usr/local/bin

```
sudo cp "first command result" /usr/local/bin
```